# Translate a PHP Array to a javascript array

Tags: php, javascript, arrays

I'm trying to convert that PHP array :

```
    Array
(
    [1] => 
Array
        (
            [ID] => 6927
            [Town] => Paris
            [latitude] => 48.867521
            [longitude] => 2.3317145
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 6928
            [Town] => Paris
            [latitude] => 48.8615398
            [longitude] => 2.3496911
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 6929
            [Town] => Paris
            [latitude] => 48.8675335
            [longitude] => 2.3292922
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [ID] => 6930
            [Town] => Paris
            [latitude] => 48.8686698
            [longitude] => 2.3413497
        )
```

to a javascript array, but I don't know how.
How can I do that?

Comment: echo "var my_js_array=" . json_encode( $my_php_array ) . ";";

Comment: You could have it print out and target it's container to convert to array. I don't know much about JSON but that's one way.

Answer (score 1):

You need to translate this into JSON. 
Have a look at this function http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Answer (score 0):

Ever heard of [JSON](http://www.json.org/)?

```
<?

$jsarray = json_encode($phpArray);

?>

<script>

var myArray = <? echo $jsarray; ?>;

</script>
```

And perhaps this helps: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.json.php